# Take elements by key in objects array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, filter, reduce

Let's say I have got an array of objects like this:

```
const a = [
 0: {name: 'John', lastName: 'Smith'}
 1: {name: 'Juan', lastName: 'Perez'}
 myKey: true
 myKey2: false
]
```

How can I extract from my array just the value of 'myKey'?
So the expected output would be

```
const myKeyValue = true
```

Comment: `a.myKey` will do it - just like with any other object. But your array literal syntax isn't valid, I assume you are referring to inspect output in the console of an array that got these keys manually added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single value and you know the key, use:

```
const myKeyValue = a.myKey
```